# Visual Studio Code Associate files to certain launch configuration

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I started using VS Code for my Java and Python assignments. I noticed, I have to select a suitable launch configuration prior debugging the file and If I hit 'F5' without changing config it's trying to debug Java file with Python interpreter or vice versa.

At the top right hand side I can see there's an option to debug the file with appropriate compiler but It doesn't work when I just press F5.

I would like to know if I can associate certain file types to certain launch configs so that whenever I switch between different file types the launch config automatically changes according to that?

Comment: not with the build in Launch configs, You can have multiple configs for the same languageID, I don't know an API call that allows you to switch launch config, have you searched the MarketPlace

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I found [this] (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.launch-config) I have to check if this works.

Comment: I did not know of the `startDebugging` API call. You then use the same key combo for all launch configs and then discriminate with the `languageId` in the `when` property